# Interrupt blocking unmanaged process in .NET

Tags: .net, interrupt, blocking

I have an unmanaged DLL that allow read from specific device (IC FTDI and the library is libmpsse). The problem is when I call *Read()* method of the library, and the device don't receive the answer (e.g. slave device is absent), it's still wait forever. No timeout realized in the library.

How can I interrupt running method from .NET in this case?

Comment: Put the code into a separate process and kill the process.

Comment: Or work with the author of the library and add some timeout mechanism in there.

Comment: @HansPassant ok, thanks! I'll use it! But what if I have few different libraries with same problem. E.g. CH341.dll etc.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen thank you! I check it now.

Comment: @HansPassant libMPSSE.dll is not contains method FT_SetTimeouts(). This method placed in ftd2xx.dll. This is not optimal solution for me import 2 libraries in the project.